# Why does my cooldown not work in python/pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this shooter cooldown, and it should go up to 10 and reset, but just continues forever. Anyone know why?

```
def update(self):
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    print(self.cooldown)

    if self.cooldown > 0:
        self.cooldown += 1
    elif self.cooldown >= 10:
        self.cooldown = 0

    if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.cooldown == 0:
        self.shoot()
        self.cooldown = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Replace `elif` with `if`: `elif self.cooldown >= 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if self.cooldown > 0:
```

is always satisfied, change it to

```
 if self.cooldown > 0 and self.cooldown < 10:
```